# Can I say "get out from the train"?

Tags: prepositions

Can I say "**get out from the train**" or do I need to use only **of** there? Are there any rules about this?

Comment: the preposition has to match the verb to the object

Comment: In my day, one would alight from a train but that kind of formal vocabulary disappeared with the much missed steam trains in days of yore.

Answer (score 1):

The most natural way to say it would be "get off the train".

But to your question, "get out of" has the meaning you're using--leave or exit.

"Out from" is typically used to refer to relative position being away, as in distant.  For example, "Plant the tree out from the house" would mean to plant it a distance away from the house, not close.  It is also used to indicate starting point and direction, as in "measure out from the wall".